# Swing with Spring troubles

Tags: java, spring, swing, autowired

I'm trying to use `@Autowired` statement in Swing application which locates in Spring Web MVC project. I just run it as Java aplication.

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import net.babobka.blog.headHunter.Converter;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainFrame implements ActionListener {
    @Autowired
    private Converter converter;    
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Project backup system");
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start"),
            stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    JLabel statusLab = new JLabel();
    BackupThread bt;

    MainFrame() {
        int eur = (int) converter.getRate("EUR", "RUB");//This is MainFrame.java:29
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        stopButton.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.setSize(275, 100);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.add(startButton);
        jfrm.add(stopButton);
        jfrm.add(statusLab);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }...
```

But `NullPointerException` is all that I've got. What's wrong with wiring? 
Full trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.babobka.blog.app.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:29)
    at net.babobka.blog.app.MainFrame$1.run(MainFrame.java:60)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

`Converter` works in other classes, except for Swing apps.

Root-context.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="net.babobka.blog" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="template" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="commonStatistic" />

                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="langStatistic" />

            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="converter" class="net.babobka.blog.headHunter.Converter" />

    <bean id="googleCharts" class="net.babobka.blog.charts.GoogleCharts" />

    <bean id="sender" class="net.babobka.blog.backupper.Sender" />

    <bean id="mainFrame" class="net.babobka.blog.app.MainFrame" />


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/db/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jdbc.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="Backupper" class="net.babobka.blog.backupper.Backupper"></bean>

    <bean id="OldDataRemoval" class="net.babobka.blog.termination.OldDataRemoval"></bean>

    <bean id="HeadHunterImport" class="net.babobka.blog.headHunter.HeadHunterImport"></bean>



    <bean id="urlForwardController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver1"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="basename" value="views" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Comment: Which line is `MainFrame.java:29`?

Comment: `int eur = (int) converter.getRate("EUR", "RUB");//This`

Comment: Is Converter supposed to be injected by Spring? Can you test if it is doing this? I've never debugged Spring myself, but surely there must be some way to do this. Does it have proper getter/setter methods?

Comment: answer is very simple  `private Converter converter;`  isn't intialized, in code posted here, reason for very clear  exception

Comment: @mKorbel: I don't think that it is as simple as that, since the `@Autowired` annotation indicates that Spring should inject a valid object into the converter field. But we don't know how he configures or runs his code, so it is difficult to see based on the information posted what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, Converter should be injected by Spring. And, no, it doesn't inject. Converter and others beans work fine in all project, except for Swing app.

Comment: I will post root-context.xml

Comment: question about your logics for cross currency rates, for why reason are defined separate as Xxx and Xxx, and not BaseCurr/VariableCurr, you safe more that half code required..., coint has always two sides, you need good StandingData

Comment: `should be injected by Spring. And, no, it doesn't inject.` maybe @HFOE is right about logics, but this is job for `Workers Thread` e.g. `Runnable#Thread` or `SwingWorker`, exception returns non_initialized Object, there is pretty asynchronous injection, logics for Swing should be create an Swing GUI, show GUI, start Workers Thread, update (already visible) Swing GUI on EDT (`invokeLater` from `Runnable#Thread`, notify Swing GUI from  `publish` or `done` by using `SwingWorker`)

Comment: Maybe @mKorbel is on to something. I don't think a SwingWorker would work in this situation, but I do wonder if the Converter field should not be in the GUI class or code. The GUI should be started on the Swing thread, and the Converter injection should likely be annotated in code that is started on the main thread. In other words, the Converter field should be in this program but in a non-GUI class that doesn't require it to be started on the EDT.

Answer (score 3):

Properties are set after construction. Try moving init code from Ctor to a initialization method.

For example

```
public class MainFrame() {

    public MainFrame() {}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        int eur = (int) converter.getRate("EUR", "RUB");
        ....
   }
}
```